# What are the dangers in performing a stunt involving flying and spinning arm bars?

Tags: stunts, martial-arts

I recently watched Birth of the Dragon and absolutely loved it. In the movie, Master Wong performs a movement in which he performs a very cinematically pleasing flying arm bar with spinning involved (timestamp included):

My biggest question surrounds the concept of ensuring the safety of both parties during such a movement. There seems to be *a lot* to worry about here from a safety aspect, such as head and neck injuries, the potential for a broken arm if something went wrong, additionally if something went *very* wrong, the legs of the attacker could be injured.

With this, what are the *biggest* safety concerns with such a movement, and how are they most commonly mitigated?